# MongoDB Chart $multiply

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-charts

I have a data like this.

```
"products": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ffd0a8f6273740017cc5fca"
        },
        "name": "Banana",
        "price": 65,
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-12T02:33:51.648Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-12T02:33:51.648Z"
        },
        "quantity": 3
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ffd09326273740017cc5fb3"
        },
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 79,
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-12T02:28:02.412Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-12T02:28:02.412Z"
        },
        "quantity": 2
    }]
```

What I'm trying to do is multiply the price over the quantity.

Implementation:

```
{ $reduce: {
  input: '$products', initialValue: 0,
  in: { $multiply: ["$products.price",
      "$products.quantity"] } }
```

I'm having an error **$multiply only supports numeric types, not array**

Comment: use `$$this.price` and `$$this.quantity` instead of `$products.price` and `$products.quantity`

Comment: @turivishal Hi, I have tried your suggestion. but it turns out both result is multiplied by the  quantity of the second product.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I expect to have a result of _banana_ 65 x 3 = 195 and _apple_ 79*2 = 158. but both result became 158. I'm doing it on mongodb charts.

Comment: I am not sure about charts, but you can try $map instead of $reduce, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DfHD3DdhWuy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the output is still the second result in mongodb charts.